# Write code in ARM7EJ-S processor with RXD and TXD pin possible?

Tags: gps, arm, iot

Currently, I'm working on a Chinese tracking device that has GPS and it tracks my bike and it sends data to an IP address xx.xx.xx.xx now I need to send all data to my own server so that I can track my dog and send push notification to the android phone. RxD pin and TxD pin both can be connected with a jumper wire. Now, how I can program to it myself. At least a start point or a guideline will help a lot.

**(This project is only for education purpose only)**

[a picture of a similar circuit is to have a better idea given here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kFXeoE-X--kU7WnW463P6CH5ui0NDXJo)

Comment: ARM7EJ-S is just the processor core. How it is programmed, whether it has an UART bootloader (required for flashing via RX/TX) depends on the concrete controller type. To program it, you will need the processors full documentation, IDE/compiler/toolchain, JTAG/SWD adapters etc. It might be much easier to build a completely new GPS tracker using e.g. Arduino and/or a more modern CPU (e.g. Cortex-A/M), possibly utilizing existing open source projects.

Comment: Thank you very much @Erlkoenig. I really appreciate your help. Your comment really helped to study much more specific points. Please, can you share a guideline how can I make things with ARM processors, it will save my life :D

Comment: That depends a lot on what you want to do and your skill level. You can get a raspberry pi and write applications much like on a PC. You can get an Arduino Due and use the easy Arduino Environment. You can use custom ARM boards and use Linux on them like with the PI, or program them bare-metal without an OS. Of course, a GPS tracker can also be built with other processors such as MIPS...